# The number of continuously increasing primes gaps in the interval $[2,n]$ is less than $\log n$

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, prime-gaps, prime-constellations

A [prime gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) is the difference between two successive prime numbers. The $n$-th prime gap, denoted gn or $g(p_n)$ is the difference between the $(n+1)$-st and the $n$-th prime numbers. Using my computer I check found that:

- In the interval $[2,10^2]$ the maximum the number of continuously strict increasing primes gaps is $3$. The fist case with $P_7=17$, $P_8=19$, $P_9=23$, $P_{10}=29$; $g_7=2$, $g_8=4$, $g_9=6$. We see that $3 < \log29=3.36$
- In the interval $[2,10^3]$ the maximum the number of continuously strict increasing primes gaps is $4$. The fist case with $P_{69}=347$, $P_{70}=349$, $P_{71}=353$, $P_{72}=359$, $P_{73}=367 $; $g_{69}=2$, $g_{70}=4$, $g_{71}=6$, $g_{72}=8$. We see that $4 < \log367=5.905$
- In the interval $[2,10^4]$ the maximum the number of continuously strict increasing primes gaps is $5$. The fist case with $P_{420}=2903$, $P_{421}=2909$, $P_{422}=2917$, $P_{423}=2927$, $P_{424}=2939$, $P_{425}=2939$, $P_{426}=2953$; $g_{420}=6$, $g_{421}=8$, $g_{422}=10$, $g_{423}=12$, $g_{424}=14$. We see that $5 < \log2953=7.99$

**Update 1**: I continued testing and confirmed that the result was correct for [the first fifty million primes](https://t5k.org/lists/small/millions/), to get the detail resutl please [click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZRGn8keOjAhLFy0LCf-Mz0Tq5wfxH_Sg/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106039353647968080751&rtpof=true&sd=true)

**My question:**

> *The number of continuously strict increasing primes gaps in the interval $[2,n]$ is less than $\log n$?*

**Update 2**:

> *The number of continuously <strike>strict</strike>  increasing primes gaps in the interval $[2,n]$ is less than $\log n$?*

Comment: Heuristically prime gaps are geometrically distributed with mean $\log n$, so the probability of an increasing run of length $i$ should be around $(\log n)^{-i^2}$, so your $i$ should have $n (\log n)^{-i^2} \approx 1$, so $i^2 \approx \frac{\log n}{\log\log n}$, and $i \approx \sqrt {\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}}$. There is probably a missing multiplicative error there.

Comment: For the first bullet point, shouldn't it be three gaps, with $17\ 19\ 23\ 29$?

Comment: For the second bullet point, $347\ 349\ 353\ 359\ 367$?

Comment: Third bullet point can also be extended to $2953$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks you Dr. Gerry Myerson. You are right, my program has an error at a command line. May I update it now?

Comment: This is a really nice problem, definitely +1!

Comment: Yes, it's better for you to update your question than for the corrections to be solely in the comments.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have just checked it true upto $9.7*10^8$, Thanks you very much